# Why is the compiler saying function already exists?

Tags: c++, fstream

I wanted to count the lines of a file, then do soemthing to it. I decided to extract the logic for counting the lines to a seperate function.

```
unsigned int countLines(std::ifstream in)
{
    string line;
    int lineCount = 0;
    while(getline(in, line))
        ++lineCount;
    return lineCount;
}
```

I declared the prototype of the function before defining any functions. However the compiler complained "previous decleration of 'unsigned int countLines(std::ifstream)' but google searching I can't find any mention of an actual countLines function in ifstream. Why is this happening? The top of the file has

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
```

No there is no header file.

I call it like const

```
ifstream inFile(filename);
unsigned int vehichles = countLines(inFile);
```

and it gives the warning note: synthesized method `'std:basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<char>&)' first required here`

Comment: Is the function defined in a header that is included in more than one place?

Comment: Did you put the function body below its first use? By the way: *surely* that error came with a line number and source file?

Comment: @Celeritas Son show the full error message. Usually compilers point out where a function was already defined.

Comment: Show your *entire* program and *unedited* error messages

Comment: And by "full error message" we mean do Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C on the whole compiler's output.

Comment: @Dialecticus: And if the editor is emacs `M-<`, `C-Spc`, `M->`, `M-W` will copy the content. Then paste it in here (in the post, not in a comment, as that becomes unreadable)

Comment: So your code looks like this? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83721935192e6ecd - Because this compiles.

Comment: The problem is you have provided us with two pieces of code that work. Now we are trying to guess what you did that may have caused your error because we don't know how those two pieces of code fit together and what other code exists, that you didn't include, that may be helping to cause this. We need more info.

Comment: You're trying to copy a `ifstream`, which are uncopyable.

Comment: why couldn't you get that from countLines(std:: **ifstream** in)?

Comment: @celeritas You posted a new error message and I was addressing that. How do you expect me to read your mind?

Comment: @Alf how's that incomplete, the first line of code (of the original question) showed it

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass a stream by value.

Comment: -1 no explination given, -1 no solution proposed

Comment: @Celeritas It's self explanatory. You can't copy an ifstream because the copy constructor is deleted. The solution is to not write code that tries to copy it.

Comment: @Celeritas: please do show some effort. **any** effort would do.

Comment: @remyabel what do you mean the copy constructor is deleted, you mean it never had one? So the solution is to always pass by reference, right?

Comment: @Celertias In C++03 mode it's private. In C++11, it's [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513881/meaning-of-delete-after-function-declaration).