# Guaranteed copy elision paper's use of void in a constructor

Tags: c++, c++17

In the [paper P0135R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html) there is an example:

```
struct NonMoveable {
  NonMoveable(int);
  NonMoveable(NonMoveable&) = delete;
  void NonMoveable(NonMoveable&) = delete;
  std::array<int, 1024> arr;
};
NonMoveable make() {
  return NonMoveable(42); // ok, directly constructs returned object
}
auto nm = make(); // ok, directly constructs 'nm'
```

This confused me:

```
void NonMoveable(NonMoveable&) = delete;
```

What is it? How constructor can be void?

UPD. Someone linked [probable answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513881/meaning-of-delete-after-function-declaration) - No! This question is totally different.

Comment: *"No! This question is totally different."* How so? If you are not asking what `=delete` does, then what are you asking?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I'm asking how *constructor* can be void?

Comment: But the constructor is *alive and kicking* and is called `NonMoveable(int)`.

Comment: @hgiesel Sorry, what?

Comment: @hgiesel That is not the issue here, it's about `void` one.

Comment: Well that is an error, constructors and deconstructors don't have return types.

Comment: So there would be two identical lines?

Comment: @MarcGlisse Doesn't look like a typo. It would make at least 2 changes to make it legit. One removing `void` and second changing argument to `&&`

Comment: Note that the current version of the paper, [P0135R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html), does not contain such an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That "void" is what we would call a "typo". The intent was likely to remove the move assignment operator (though not strictly necessary, since deleting the copy constructor would do that). Considering that the person wrote "void", it's not surprising that the person also missed the `&&` part, and forgot the `const` in the copy constructor's parameter (also not strictly necessary).

Basically, there's a lot wrong there; someone wrote it in a hurry.

Comment: It's likely meant to delete the copy assignment. Just deleting the copy constructor won't do the job.

Comment: You misspelled Typevoido