# Vector of Ofstream objects cannot be created

Tags: c++

```
ofstream out_data1, out_data2;
vector<ofstream> {out_data1, out_data2};
```

Error image :
[image: compiling error is detected]
Why is this happening? How can I solve it?

Comment: If you don't take the effort to even paste the code and error message into the question, you're not going to get much help.

Comment: ofstream copy constructor is deleted

Comment: Sorry guys. Don't know how to copy paste a red-underlined error but the image contains all the information needed.

Comment: @Elijay, copy constructor is deleted. Move ctor is not...

Comment: The error seems to tell you that the copy constructor of a base class of ofstream is deleted (a way to forbid its use). And your vector definition seems to be invoking that copy constructor. First, I would name the vector. Second, try using a vector of ofstream&. Third, do you really need that?

Comment: To get plain text: compile the program then copy the build output and paste it into the question.  Formatting the error message as a code block often helps keep the message readable. The compiler is the final arbiter and spends the time to make sure the results are as correct as possible and provide a complete error message. Sometimes pages and pages of of complete error message. The squiggly underlines and pop-up messages are helpful, but they aren't always correct. This one is correct, but precision matters and you should provide the compiler output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a careful [look at this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/), you will understand that you are trying to copy an `ofstream` object, and the `copy constructor` of `ofstream` [is deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513881/meaning-of-delete-after-function-declaration). That is what the error is telling you. You could have simply searched for the error on Google though ;)

Comment: So "vector<ofstream> {out_data1, out_data2};" actually creates two new objects which copies the value of the original objects?

Comment: Of course. You are using the [brace-initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives)

Comment: @PoloLi Note that the compiler may optimize out the copying and construct in place, but the object must still be copy-able

Comment: In this case I'm thinking more [the As-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). I think there may be too many layers involved here for honest-to-god copy elision. TL:DR version of the As-if Rule: If there's no change to the observable behaviour, the compiler can do whatever it wants.

Comment: So what I can do is to "vector.pushback() " all the elements or create a vector of ofstream pointers? Or are there other suggestions?

Comment: Seems like an xy-problem. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: @PoloLi You cannot copy a stream, but [you can move it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics).

Comment: @d4rk4ng31I just wanna manipulate a bunch of ofstream objects and apply for loops on them.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 I've learned the basic file handling and the code works well before if I don't create a vector of Ofstreams. What I'm trying to do is to output four csv files.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Ok I'll start to learn that. Thank you very much!