# C++ error : non deleted function cannot override a deleted function

Tags: c++

I implemented the following base class and derived classes respectively

```cpp
class observerInterface {
public:
    virtual void update(std::string data) = delete;
    virtual const std::string & getUniqueID() = delete;

private:
    //deleting copy constructor and copy operator.
    observerInterface(const observerInterface &) = delete;
    observerInterface & operator=(const observerInterface &) = delete;
};
```

```cpp
class observer1 final : public observerInterface {

    static constexpr auto UNIQUE_ID = "observer1";

public:
    void update(std::string data) override;
    const std::string & getUniqueID() override;
};
```

I am facing the following error :

```sh
nondeleted function overrides deleted function "observerInterface::******"C/C++(1789).
```

The issue is not present when I don't delete the `update` and  `getUniqueID` methods in the base class.

Any idea why I obtain this error?

I am using MSVC compiler version : 19.16.27032.1

Comment: If you want to define pure virtual functions, please, use `= 0` instead of `= delete`.

Comment: This works. What is the difference between using =0 and =delete ?

Comment: "pure virtual" is C++ name for functions that other languages call "abstract". Deleted functions are a completely different concept.

Comment: `= delete` deletes the method. `= 0` makes it pure. It would be easier to list the ways that they're *the same*.

Comment: `= 0` for a virtual function makes it pure (and the class abstract). `= delete` (regardless of virtual or not) makes it deleted. That's the difference. ;-) Deleting a function means to exclude a function from a class if (otherwise) the compiler would generate it itself internally or inherit it (from a base class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are deleting the functions:

```cpp
virtual void update(std::string data) = delete;    
virtual const std::string & getUniqueID() = delete;
```

These functions are deleted and their use is disabled by the compiler.

If instead, you intend to force these functions to be overriden, you should instead use:

```cpp
virtual void update(std::string data) = 0;    
virtual const std::string & getUniqueID() = 0;
```

which means that you declare the methods to be pure virtual.

A `pure virtual function` is a `virtual function` that is not required to have a body implementation (however, it is possible that the class can provide a `default` implementation to such functions), and thus is required to be implemented by a derived class (which means a pure virtual member function must always be implemented by a derived class that is intended to be the concrete [non virtual] ).

As I understand it, you try to derive your `observerInterface` class then a pure virtual method is adequate to what you try to do.

More details on [deleted functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513881) and [virtual functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-virtual-functions-and-abstract-classes/) and [default implementation for pure virtual functions](https://rvarago.medium.com/default-implementation-for-pure-virtual-functions-in-c-3c525cc820af) and [pure virtual implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089083/pure-virtual-function-with-implementation).

Comment: "*A pure virtual function is a virtual function that has no body implementation*" - more accurately, it is a virtual function that is *not required* to have a body, but it *can* have a default body which descendants can call if they want, but the compiler won't complain if that body is missing. "*and thus is required to be implemented by a derived class*" - yes, a pure virtual function MUST be overridden in a derived class. But if the base class *does* provide a default body, the derived class chooses whether it wants to call it or not.

Comment: Thanks @Remy for your excellent ( as always ;) ) review. I added the precision. :)