# error C2059: syntax error c++ code on `= delete` in vs10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I have problem with this code:

```
// Make it Non Copyable 


FileLogger (const FileLogger &) = delete;
FileLogger &operator= (const FileLogger &) = delete;
```

I need solve to this error:

```
Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : ';' 
Error   2   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

This error happen 16 time with same syntax in the same code line posted above.

Comment: Which version of visual C++ compiler are you using?

Comment: What are you expecting to do exactly? This synthax seems wrong in so many ways I don't even...

Comment: I don't understand that syntax at all. What are you trying to do?
Is FileLogger a function, and if so how can you assign it to "delete"?
Post more info so maybe I can help.

Comment: @Havenard That should be valid syntax in [C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458741/with-explicitly-deleted-member-functions-in-c11-is-it-still-worthwhile-to-inh).

Comment: @greatwolf Really? And what exactly are those supposed to mean?

Comment: @Havenard: Deleting a function means that you're defining it not to exist, so that any code that tries to call it gives a compile-time error. In this case, it's making is impossible to copy the class, as the comment says. But it won't work with a pre-2011 compiler, since it's a fairly new language feature.

Comment: @Havenard Also check out the question I linked  in my second comment.

Comment: @RamiHelmy  FileLogger is a class that perform logging text to file

Comment: @SecurityCrazy ok got it. I think you already have the answer by now :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour So basically its suppressing the compiler's attempt to create some of the special member functions (copy constructors)? Thats very interesting. How would that be done in a previous version of C++?

Comment: Nevermind, poolie answered that too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you're trying to use the [new C++11 `= delete` syntax](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#default) to suppress the default  implementation. I think this error means that this compiler just doesn't understand that syntax.

In pre-C++11 compilers the typical approach is to instead use [`DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN` macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1454407/243712) that end up declaring the constructor/assignment as private.

Comment: plz , can you tell me more how can i use DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN macros in my class .

Comment: If you just delete those lines, the code should compile just fine. This code is telling the compiler it has to disallow attempts to copy the class, throwing a compile time error. If you remove the code it will allow copy, but depending on the case that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @SecurityCrazy [How to disable the copy constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077143/disable-copy-constructor) and do the same for `operator=`.

Answer (score 0):

In pre-C++11, [`delete` is a reserved word](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword). That means it has special meaning to the compiler and can't be used for anything else. If that's the name of one of your variables, rename it and you should be fine.

Comment: This is actually legit -- what he's trying to achieve is part of C++11.

Comment: I'm leaving this answer here deliberately (and community-wikifying it) so as to avoid confusion for future visitors, but @poolie is correct.

Comment: is it any way to perform it by my current c++ version

Comment: @SecurityCrazy: This C++11 syntax only became available in VS2013.